# pm-hibernate shutdown the PC

Tags: power-management, hibernate

I have recently installed pm-hibernate and running `Sudo pm-hibernate`. suddenly my PC gets off (not proper shut down). When trying to restart the pc all my works are gone and it starts as a fresh. Can anyone help me with this? Also if possible please let me know how to hibernate without entering the password ( I want to write a script for auto hibernate when battery is below 10 %)

Comment: Do you have SWAP space defined? You need 1.25 times RAM. Read `man pm-is-supported` and see its various options.

Comment: I have 7.7 GB of RAM and 7.7 GB of swap. pm-is-supported gave me `pm-is-supported [--suspend | --hibernate | --suspend-hybrid ]` output

Comment: You should have read the `man` page first. Do something like `for i in suspend hibernate suspend-hybrid ; do /bin/echo -en "$i\t" ; (pm-is-supported --$i;echo "$?") ; done`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this small utility to auto make Logoff, Screensaver, shutdown suspend and Hibernate .  Just compile it with your sound listed it the program code.  Chmod u+x the filename once complied with g++.   I use a small script file on the desktop to launch the program and run in Terminal.

## include

using namespace std;

## define bold_on "\e[1m"

## define bold_off "\e[22m"

## define red_on "\033[31m"

## define reset "\033[0m"

## define yellow "\033[33m"

## define b_green "\033[1m\033[32m"

//======================================================================

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

char answer;

cout << b_green "\n\n Please make you choice? Any other key to quit the program. \n" reset << endl;

cout << bold_on red_on "      S"  bold_off reset yellow" - Shutdown the Computer"  << endl;
  cout << bold_on red_on "      R"  bold_off reset yellow" - Restart the Computer"<< endl; 
  cout << bold_on red_on "      L"  bold_off reset yellow" - Logoff the Computer"<< endl;
  cout << bold_on red_on "      U"  bold_off reset yellow" - Suspend the Computer"<< endl;
  cout << bold_on red_on "      H"  bold_off reset yellow" - Hybernate the Computer"<< endl;
  cout << bold_on red_on "      X"  bold_off reset yellow" - Lock the Computer \n\n" red_on;

cin >> answer;

```
    if( answer=='L' ) {
     system("cinnamon-session-quit"); 
     system("paplay /home/dad/Music/desktop-logout.wav");

    } else if( answer=='R' ) {
     system("paplay /home/dad/Music/desktop-logout.wav");
     system("systemctl reboot") ;             

    } else if (answer =='S') { 
     system("paplay /home/dad/Music/desktop-logout.wav");
     system("systemctl poweroff" );

    } else if (answer =='U') { 
     system("paplay /home/dad/Music/desktop-logout.wav");
     system("systemctl suspend");

    } else if (answer =='X') { 
     system("paplay /home/dad/Music/desktop-logout.wav");
     system("cinnamon-screensaver-command -l");

    } else if (answer =='H') { 
     system("paplay /home/dad/Music/desktop-logout.wav");
     system("systemctl hibernate");


  }
```

}
here is my script file on my desktop.

## !/bin/bash

/home/dad/LRS
exit

my program is LRS you can name it anything you want.